# Android layout - Screen wont move up to allow input in EditText at the bottom

Tags: android

Hopefully this is just something easy since I'm still wet behind the ears with programming for android. My issue is that i have a couple EditText boxes at the bottom of my layout. When in the emulator they work as expected, you touch the edittext and the screen scrolls up so you can see the content. However when i try it on my droid inc the edittext is covered by the keyboard.

See screen captures at links (can't post them since I'm new...)

[Droid Screen capture](http://www.revta.com/Stack%20Overflow/device.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to implement [**`ScrollView`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)  so that whenever you added more controls inside any Layout, it will then allows you to scroll up and down.

Have a look at [**this example**](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-scrollview-example/) , it will sure help you for understanding `ScrollView`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Allowed the screen to scroll when keyboard came up on screen.

Thank you!

Comment: @hydrox467..yeh glad to know your reply